# Nodejs Скачать изображения с сервера и положить в нужную папку?

Tags: node.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на nodejs должен выглядеть код который будет скачивать картинку по указанному адресу (К примеру картинку https://ibb.co/X44SCpN) и класть в определенную папку.
Или что надо знать что б это реализовать? В какую сторону копать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно установить модуль [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

function downloadFile(url, path) {
  return fetch(url).then(res => {
    res.body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
  });
}

// Using
downloadFile('https://i.ibb.co/QccrKnz/artboar8d-53.jpg','/tmp/artboar8d-53.jpg')
   .then(()=>console.log('OK'))
   .catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

Я сделал еще небольшой код, который скачивает страницу IBB, парсит эту страницу, ищет ссылку оригинальной картинки на странице и скачивает картинку сохраняя файл в папку (не спрашивая полного адреса к файлу - достаточно указать папку), в конце результатом выдает путь к картинке. Дополнительно требует модуль [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio).

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const path = require('path');

async function downloadIBB(pageUrl, folder){
  const res = await fetch(pageUrl);
  const page = await res.text();
  const $ = cheerio.load(page);
  const imgUrl = $('link[rel="image_src"]').attr('href');
  const filename = path.basename(imgUrl);
  const filepath = path.join(folder,filename);
  const imgRes = await fetch(imgUrl);
  return new Promise(res=>{
    filestream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
    imgRes.body.pipe(filestream);
    filestream.on('finish',()=>res(filepath));
  });
}


// Using
downloadIBB('https://ibb.co/X44SCpN','/tmp')
   .then((path)=>console.log(path))
   .catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

Comment: Что-то не срабатывает. И вот эта строка downloadFile('https://ibb.co/X44SCpN','/tmp/X44SCpN.jpg')  Не очень понятна, первый параметр ясен - адрес скачиваемого файла, а вот второй? По логике оно должно скачать файл в папку tmp с именем X44SCpN.jpg ? (А если название файла мне неизвестно, можно как-то его называть по url скачиваемой картинки)

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Писал на скорую руку, сейчас чуть сократил код, попробуйте.
Да, там  два параметра: url и путь к файлу.

Comment: Оно вроде как что-то скачивает. *Файл создается, но открыть его не получатся

Comment: Да, он скачивает HTML-код, а сохраняет в `.jpg`, надо бы конечно в `.html`. Что-то я не подумал

Comment: @BlackStar1991 вот теперь точно берет то что нужно и сохраняет куда надо

Comment: @BlackStar1991 попробуйте новый код, который только что дополнил в ответе